# Finding marginal pdf

Tags: probability

I'm given a joint pdf with the following bounds

$$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
x^2 & \text{for} & 0 \leq y \leq 1-x^2 \\[1ex] 
0 &:& \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

I am trying to find the Marginal pdf of y. I thought the integral would be from -1 to 1 since that's what it seems to be bound by on the graph, but that's wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw the downward-facing parabola $y=1-x^2$. To find the (marginal) density of the random variable $y$, we "integrate out" $x$.

But first we need to make a fix. The "density" is not a density, since the double integral of our "density" over the region below the parabola and above the $x$-axis is $\frac{4}{15}$. To make it a density we need to use $\frac{15}{4}x^2$, not $x^2$.

It is clear that the density is $0$  outside the interval $[0,1]$. Inside the interval, we go from $x=-\sqrt{1-y}$ (the left branch of the parabola) to $x=\sqrt{1-y}$ (the right branch). So inside the interval we want
$$\int_{x=-\sqrt{1-y}}^{\sqrt{1-y}} \frac{15}{4} x^2\,dx.$$
Integrate. We get $\frac{5}{2}(1-y)^{3/2}$ on the interval $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f_Y(y)=\int_{-\sqrt{1-y}}^{\sqrt{1-y}}x^2dx=\dfrac{2(1-y)^{3/2}}{3}$$ for $0<y<1$.

Comment: how did you get the limits of integration?

Comment: @risdel from the support: $0< y < 1- x^2 < 1$. This means that $1>1-y>x^2>0$, which in turn means that ${-}\sqrt{1-y}<x<\sqrt{1-y}$ and $0<y<1$.

Comment: would it be safe to assume an absolute value relationship where 
x^2 ≤(1−y) =>    −√(1 − y) ≤ x ≤√(1−y)

Comment: @risdel Yes.  It is algebraically reasonable to do so.  Plot $\,y= 1-x^2\,$.  The area below this curve and above the x-axis is the support of the joint distribution.  Draw a series of horizontal line segments across this area (particularly at $y=0.36$ and $y=0.64$). From this we can see from the plot we have $\,x\in\big({-}\sqrt{1-y\,}..{+}\sqrt{1-y\,}\big)\,$ for each $\,y\in\big(0..1\big)\,$.